# How to check for GUID in ng-if condition

Tags: angularjs

My property in a class is returning a GUID as GUID object not a string, how to check that in ng-if statement ? I am doing it below way but it is not working

```
 <div ng-if="myclass.Id == "XXXX-XXXXX-XXXX"">
```

Is there any way to convert into tostring() ?

Comment: Did you try with single inverted commas in the code shown - `<div ng-if="myclass.Id == 'XXXX-XXXXX-XXXX'">`. I think this is the issue.

Comment: but .ID returns GUID object not a string , will it work ?

Comment: Check it if it is working without `'..'`, if not then remove the single inverted commas.

Comment: If `myClass.Id` returns a GUID object, you need to convert it to a string before == 'XXXX-XXXX-XXXX'. What does the GUID object look like?

Comment: Give sample value for `myclass.Id`

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to write a comparation method in your controller and invoke it in ng-if.

Comment: You don't have to but it's definitely best practice. Keep the logic out of the HTML and makes it easier to modify in a single place

Answer (score 0):

You could create a filter that takes the guid object and transforms it to a string and use it like this:

```
<div ng-if="(myclass.Id | guid ) === 'XXXX-XXXXX-XXXX'">
```